# Is generating Anychart Qlik extension chart objects possible?

Tags: qliksense, anychart

We are looking at a solution involving generation of chart objects using the Anychart Qlik Sense extension.

This would be similar to using:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2019/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/VisualizationAPI/VisualizationAPI.htm

to generate native Qlik charts.

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

Thanks